# Cyclic subgroup in the $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Show that $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}$ generates an infinity cyclic subgroup in the $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ group.

Is it ok to prove that the pattern is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}^k = \begin{pmatrix}1 & k\\
0&1\end{pmatrix}$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and then show that these matrices are isomorphic with group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: Yes, Do remember to check for negative $k$ in your proof.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes! I have proof for k<0, k>0 and for k=0.

Comment: @RobArthan So, $\phi: SL(n,\mathbb{Z}) \to (\mathbb{Z},+) \\  \phi : \begin{pmatrix}1 & k\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto k$? And prove for this function?

Comment: Yes. $\phi$ is the isomorphism you are interested in.